# How keep a specific element pre-selected in dropdown?

Tags: reactjs

I am displaying dynamic dropdown, where I want to keep one specific element or first element selected. But I could not find way.

```
<select onChange = {this.handleSelectChange}>                 
    <option>any-select</option>
    {                     
        this.state.data2.map(function(data) {                
          return  <option value={data.id}>{data.name}</option>                                                             
        })         
    }                    
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below mentioned code

```
 this.state.data2.map(function(data,index) {                
     return index==0?<option value={data.id} selected="selected">{data.name}</option>:<option value={data.id}>{data.name}</option>                                                            
    })
```

Comment: @niravjobanputra: my bad I have updated my ans remove first curly brac

Comment: its working for random :) thank you...can you tell me for specific element?

Comment: @niravjobanputra: then accept it and up vote  it  :)

Comment: @niravjobanputra: if you want specific element then put the condition like data.id==2?<option>:<option>

Answer (score 1):

Although you can add `selected="selected"` on option, but I think the better way is using `value` of select.
You can change the `value` of select in `onChange` handler.
If you want select the first no-value option, just set `value` to a false value such as `null`

```
<select onChange = {this.handleSelectChange} value={/*null or selected option's data.id*/}>                 
    <option>any-select</option>
    {                     
        this.state.data2.map(function(data) {                
            return  <option value={data.id}>{data.name}</option>                                                             
        })         
    }                    
</select>
```

If you want to select any other option, just set `value` to the option's value